# Speed issues with pandas and list comprehensions

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

I have a dataset with 4m rows of data, and I split this into chunks using pd.read_csv(chunk size...) and then perform some simple data cleaning code to get it into a format I need.

```
tqdm.pandas()
print("Merging addresses...")

df_adds = chunk.progress_apply(merge_addresses, axis = 1)

[(chunk.append(df_adds[idx][0], ignore_index=True),chunk.append(df_adds[idx][1], \
ignore_index=True)) for idx in tqdm(range(len(chunk))) \
if pd.notnull(df_adds[idx][0]['street_address'])]


def merge_addresses(row):
    row2 = pd.Series(
            {'Org_ID' : row.Org_ID,
            'org_name': row.org_name,
            'street_address': row.street_address2})
    row3 = pd.Series(
            {'Org_ID' : row.Org_ID,
            'org_name': row.org_name,
            'street_address': row.street_address3})
    return row2, row3
```

I'm using tqdm to analyse the speed of two operations, the first, a pandas apply function runs fine at about 1.5k it/s, and the second, a list comprehension starts at about 2k it/s then quickly drops to 200 it/s. Can anyone help explain how I can improve the speed of this?

My aim is to take the street_address 2 & 3 and merge and copy all of them that aren't null into the street_address1 column, duplicating the org_id and org_name as required.

**Update**

I've tried to capture any NaNs in merge_addresses and replace them as strings. My aim is to bring address2 and address3 into their own row (with org_name and org_id (so these two fields will be duplicates) in the same column as address1. So potentially there could be three rows for the same org_id but the addresses vary.

```
df_adds = chunk.progress_apply(merge_addresses, axis = 1)

[(chunk.append(x[0]), chunk.append(x[1])) for x in tqdm(df_adds) if (pd.notnull(x[0][3]),pd.notnull(x[0][3]))]

def merge_addresses(row):
    if pd.isnull(row.street_address2):
        row.street_address2 = ''
    if pd.isnull(row.street_address3):
        row.street_address3 = ''
    return ([row.Org_ID, row.pub_name_adj, row.org_name, row.street_address2], [row.Org_ID, row.pub_name_adj, row.org_name, row.street_address3])
```

I'm getting the error `'<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)`

Using tqdm, the list comprehension appears to be work, but it's painfully slow (24 it/s)

**Update**

Just to clarify, the data is in the current format:
[image]

And my aim is to get it to the following:

[image]

I've played around with different chunk sizes:

> 20k row = 70 it/s 100k row = 35 it/s 200k = 31 it/s

It seems that the better size for the trade-off is 200k rows.

Comment: `df_adds[idx]` is a complicated object which occupies a lot of memory. So when millions of objects appended to a dataframe / list, the operation will slow down. Try using builtin types (str, int) instead of objects. In this case, replace pd.Series with simpler rows.

Comment: The objects not only contains the data (street_address) but also a dictionary of methods and a reference to itself. Thus it's much more than a "primitive" data. There is no need to store a list of pd.Series, you may replace the list of pd.Series with a single pd.Series with cols you need.

Comment: Thanks - I replaced the pd.series in merge_addresses() with just dictionaries. There's an overall increase in it/s however the slowdown still occurs about 30% into the operation. Can I just confirm that the list comprehension itself looks ok? I'm quite new to these.

Comment: @knh190 would you mind writing this up as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As proved in comments, the bottleneck here is caused by creating & feeding too many objects, which is eating up too much memory. Also creating an object costs memory allocation time and slows it down.

Proved on 100k dataset:

```
# create sample dataframe
s = []
for i in range(100000):
    s.append(tuple(['name%d' %i, 'a%d' %i, 'b%d' %i]))

labels = ['name', 'addr1', 'addr2']
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=labels)

# addr1, addr2 to addr
s = []
for k in ['addr1', 'addr2']:
    s.append(df.filter(['id', 'name', k]).rename(columns={k:'addr'}))
result = pd.concat(s)
```

`df.append` is much slower than list's builtin `append`. The example finishes within a few second.

Comment: The chunk.append(df_adds[x][0]) part is giving the error:
`RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects` I think this is due to NaNs, however when I replace these with empty strings in merge_addresses, still the error shows.

Comment: @DavidM it's caused by comparison between `str` and `int`, they are not comparable. I suppose it's raised by `if not x[-1]`. Does `if pd.notnull(x[-1])` work for you?

Comment: @DavidM or I think you need to update your code. I didn't see what's it right now.

Comment: I've updated my question a bit to show you. I've tried to capture any NaNs in merge_addresses and replace them as strings. My aim is to bring address2 and address3 into their own row (with org_name and org_id (so these two fields will be duplicates) in the same column as address1. So potentially there could be three rows for the same org_id but the addresses vary.

Comment: @DavidM Sorry for late update! See latest answer if there's any more problem. (p.s. I've just noticed, why are you appending new records to an existing `chunk`?)

Comment: no problem at all :) I've updated my answer to show the format I'm trying to get the data to. I'm adding to the existing chunk because I thought it would be slower to create another data frame too.  Perhaps I should try just creating a whole new dataframe?

Comment: @DavidM there's no need to create a new dataframe. It already provided a bunch of useful and efficient operations! See `df.filter`, `df.dropna` to filter out data etc. If you append to the existing dataframe it actually causes data inconsistency (and it's slow).

Comment: @DavidM last update: this is the furthest I can go for it.

Comment: You are a legend. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @DavidM if the answer's helpful, you may click upvote. Thank you!

Comment: upvoted and accepted :) it/s increased from 30 to 10,000 :D

Answer (score 2):

Calling `DataFrame.append` too frequently can be expensive (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

> Iteratively appending rows to a DataFrame can be more computationally intensive than a single concatenate. A better solution is to append those rows to a list and then concatenate the list with the original DataFrame all at once.

If you can, use `pd.concat` for a speedier implementation.